# Odd number pattern in C language

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me how to print the following pattern in C:

```
1
13
135
1357
13579
```

(From OP comment:)

I tried this but it prints each value two times a row:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(void) { 
    int i,j,limit; 
    printf("limit"); 
    fflush( stdout ); 
    scanf("%d",&limit); 
    for(i=1;i<=limit;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(j%2==1){ 
                printf("%d",j); 
            }
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: For each even number it will repeat the previous line of odd number sequence - to avoid that change "i" loop to `for(i=1;i<=limit;i+=2) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints each number twice, once for that value (the odd value) and again on the following value (the even value).

Better would be to loop over just the odd numbers and avoid that worry (and also avoid the additional test for odd):

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(void) { 
    int i,j,limit; 
    printf("limit"); 
    fflush( stdout ); 
    scanf("%d",&limit); 
    for(i=1;i<=limit;i+=2){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j+=2){
            printf("%d",j); 
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```